# Using AND in a, PHP, query but not/ignore the AND if its value is not selected/null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using two different checkbox dropdown menus but both the menus use the same submit button (both are in the same form for submitting).

On submit, the checkboxes that are selected are being displayed in a table to the user. The options in each menu are linked in the database to a separate column (so menu 1 has values/options that belong to column A and menu 2 has values/options that belong to column B).

In my php code i got a foreach that checks the selected checkboxes and it passes those in a variable. This variable is being used in the query. Though, the problem is, when a user selects an option in BOTH menus, the query should specify the search with the use of an AND (the value of menu 1 AND the value of menu 2 must be in the results - if one of them isn't it should return nothing), but there is also a possibility that ONLY a checkbox is selected in menu 1, if this is done then the second AND in the query (for column B/menu2 in the database) should be ignored. The question however is, is this possible?

**The HTML code:**

```
<form method="post">
<div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list">
        <span class="anchor">Select type of Living Lab</span>
        <ul class="items">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Physical_location" />Physical location</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Virtual_network" />Virtual network</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Project" />Project</li>      
        </ul>
    </div>  

<div id="list2" class="dropdown-check-list">
        <span class="anchor">Select stage of Living Lab</span>
        <ul class="items">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Starting_phase" />Starting phase</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Running_phase" />Running phase</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Completed" />Completed</li>      
        </ul>
    </div>  

<input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**The PHP foreach that passes the checkbox submit values into a search variable for the query:**

```
foreach($_POST['columns'] as $key_post=>$value_post){ 
// Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.
    $clean_criteria = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['columns']);

    // Convert the array into a string.
    $criteria = implode($clean_criteria,"|");               
}
```

**The query code:**

```
$tmp = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT
            type_of_living_lab, stage_of_living_lab         
        FROM           
            wp_participants_database            
        WHERE 
            type_of_living_lab REGEXP ('$criteria') AND stage_of_living_lab REGEXP ('$criteria')            
        ORDER BY 
            name_of_living_lab ASC
    ");
```

In the query the AND is not working because if there is nothing selected in either menu 1 or menu 2, the $criteria for the AND is not in the database thus not true (which will return nothing). An OR is not possible since the query must specify the search (both submitted values should be in the database/results if they are both selected in the checkboxes)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In your foreach loop, aren't you overriding the $criteria variable on each loop?

Comment: @Pierre-EmmanuelLevesque, I think `implode` will make concatenation.

In your case, you have to use 2 veriables.

Comment: Implode concatenates the $clean_criteria array into the $criteria string, but on the next loop this happens again thus by overriding $criteria on each loop.

Comment: Also, shouldn't those be radio buttons, i.e. one check per group.

Comment: @Kristiyan could you explain it a bit further. Should i change the second menus name into something else than columns[] and then make a second foreach for the menu? And doesn't a second variable still do the same with the AND? If the checkbox is not selected it sets the var to nothing and the AND still doesn't match in the query thus it outputs nothing at all..

Comment: @Pierre-Emmanuel Levesque nope it doesnt, also tested it with a simple echo after the foreach statement and when selecting multiple values it just simply concatenates and outputs/echos all the selected options.

Comment: Hmmm, the way you wrote it $criteria should be overwritten on each loop, and it seems to me you should only be having one stage of living lab at a time, i.e. you can't be at the starting phase and the completed phase at the same time. (I'm just asking to make sure before providing a solution.)

Comment: @Nicolas, all right. To prevent "empty AND" case, you should have 3 queries. 
1 - first variable is empty
2 - second variable is empty
3 - no one variable is empty.

Comment: @Pierre-Emmanuel Levesque if i am not mistaken the array_map makes sure that the values aren't overwritten (could be wrong though). As for the stages, your absolutely right on that, it are actually radio buttons but for explaining / testing purpose i am using them as checkboxes since there will be another menu that actually uses checkboxes.

Comment: You can build your where query independently. 

Your foreach loops is not useful since you don't use the $key_post or $value_post variables you are generating. $criteria gets overwritten like I was thinking, but you basically run the same code every loop using $_REQUEST. Just remove the foreach loop.

Comment: @Kristiyan this makes sense, thank you. Though, are you sure there inst a shorter/more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Alright, thank you all! Will do the multiple if statements with the 3 queries. @Pierre-Emmanuel Levesque ill also remove the foreach if it is unnecessary, which also kinda makes sense;). Thank you.

Comment: You could do: WHERE (type_of_living_lab REGEXP ('$criteria') AND stage_of_living_lab REGEXP ('$criteria')) OR type_of_living_lab REGEXP ('$criteria') OR stage_of_living_lab REGEXP ('$criteria')

Comment: @Pierre-Emmanuel Levesque This doesnt seem to work, because the OR statement will also be excecuted when i select options in both menus. This will cause displaying all results with $criteria in them while you only want the results that both match the $criteria of stage and type if you selected options in both. So when i select an option in menu stage and a option in menu type then it should give results where both of those 2 match. For example: type selected: project, stage selected: completed - this should give only results where the type is project and stage is completed.

Comment: Strange, it should work. OR should do either of the options, not all. I wrote the AND option first to check it first, if that doesn't work only then should it go to the OR. I put parenthesis around the AND option for that.

Comment: @Pierre-Emmanuel Levesque Yep, it should work. BUt i copied your line in and it just selects everything when it should only do the AND. Else i just use the multiple if variables.